# Scheduling multiple emails PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, scheduled-tasks, phpmailer

I've made a system that receives a query, executes it at the database and then creates an HTML table with the data returned. These tables are then saved in the system for further access, and the user can send it via email to multiple receivers.

All works well, but now I have to schedule the emails. Need to send "table X" at a week from now and "table Y" at two weeks. How can I do that? I've looked up for CRONS/WindowsTasks but I don't know how I would make it automatic for every table, since the user can keep creating different tables.

I've used CodeIgniter and PHPMailerMaster to make it happen.

Here is a screenshot of the TableViewer, it's in portuguese, but it contains:

|TITLE | CONFIG | SEND | XLS GENERATOR | LAST SENT |

For each table created. (Just so you can understand how it works)

[image]

If anyone got any ideas.

Comment: I think you do not require to manage 2 tables. It may achieve with a single table

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that simulates crontab in PHP. You can use this for dynamic crontabs, so each table can have it's own unique frequency.

```
function parse_crontab($time, $crontab) {
    // Get current minute, hour, day, month, weekday
    $time = explode(' ', date('i G j n w', strtotime($time)));
    // Split crontab by space
    $crontab = explode(' ', $crontab);
    // Foreach part of crontab
    foreach ($crontab as $k => &$v) {
        // Remove leading zeros to prevent octal comparison, but not if number is already 1 digit
        $time[$k] = preg_replace('/^0+(?=\d)/', '', $time[$k]);
        // 5,10,15 each treated as seperate parts
        $v = explode(',', $v);
        // Foreach part we now have
        foreach ($v as &$v1) {
            // Do preg_replace with regular expression to create evaluations from crontab
            $v1 = preg_replace(
                // Regex
                array(
                    // *
                    '/^\*$/',
                    // 5
                    '/^\d+$/',
                    // 5-10
                    '/^(\d+)\-(\d+)$/',
                    // */5
                    '/^\*\/(\d+)$/'
                ),
                // Evaluations
                // trim leading 0 to prevent octal comparison
                array(
                    // * is always true
                    'true',
                    // Check if it is currently that time, 
                    $time[$k] . '===\0',
                    // Find if more than or equal lowest and lower or equal than highest
                    '(\1<=' . $time[$k] . ' and ' . $time[$k] . '<=\2)',
                    // Use modulus to find if true
                    $time[$k] . '%\1===0'
                ),
                // Subject we are working with
                $v1
            );
        }
        // Join 5,10,15 with `or` conditional
        $v = '(' . implode(' or ', $v) . ')';
    }
    // Require each part is true with `and` conditional
    $crontab = implode(' and ', $crontab);
    // Evaluate total condition to find if true
    return eval('return ' . $crontab . ';');
}
```

It's used like this. First parameter is the current time, or time you want to check, second parameter is the crontab.

```
$time_to_run = parse_crontab(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), '* * * * *')
```